# Can you change unlock pin after encrypting your phone?

Tags: security, encryption

I'm using Android M and would like to turn on encryption.

Am I going to be able to change my screen pin in the future after I enable encryption?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. You can. Changing the PIN in turn changes the encryption password

From [Android Security Internals: An In-Depth Guide to Android's Security](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=y11NBQAAQBAJ&pg=PA262&lpg=PA262&dq=Additionally,+passwords+are+limited+to+16+characters+%28a+limit+that+is+hardwired+in+the+framework+and+not+configurable%29,&source=bl&ots=nUZvHPuT4x&sig=0CwMaAF8FxiQ81JjbruBk3Fs8VI&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwicmp2kqrnOAhWHQo8KHeLvCbMQ6AEIHzAA#v=onepage&q=Additionally%2C%20passwords%20are%20limited%20to%2016%20characters%20%28a%20limit%20that%20is%20hardwired%20in%20the%20framework%20and%20not%20configurable%29%2C&f=false) :

> Android doesn’t have a dedicated setting to manage the encryption pass-
>   word after the device is encrypted, and changing the screen lock password or
>   PIN will also silently change the device encryption password. This is most
>   probably a usability-driven decision: most users would be confused by having
>   to remember and enter two different passwords at different times and would
>   probably quickly forget the less frequently used, and possibly more complex,
>   disk encryption password. While this design is good for usability, it effectively
>   forces users to use a simple disk encryption password, because they have to
>   enter it each time they unlock the device, usually dozens of times a day. No
>   one wants to enter a complex password that many times, and thus most users
>   opt for a simple numeric PIN (unless a device policy requires otherwise)